# Safe coding for implementing binary encoding characters in C?

Tags: c, ascii

I have a part of a program where I need to randomize characters in a string but am interested in how to do this in such a way that the program is portable to systems that may not encode characters with ASCII.

Currently I just assign random integers corresponding to a range of values in the ASCII table.

Similar to how you may do something like 'sizeof(int)', how may you safely code an assignment of random characters?

I know you could create a static array with each character present and assign a character from a random index, but I was curious to see if there was an alternative.

Comment: Are you only interested in alphanumeric characters? Or the whole character set?

Comment: Just the alphanumeric characters will suffice. What would be the difference if I also wanted the whole set?

Comment: Working with alphanumeric characters is partially independent from the character set since their values have to be "contiguos" (sorry for poor english): 'A', 'B', ... 'Z', the same for digits. EDIT: **no**, sorry, this is only required for digits.

Comment: Even if there was a way to randomly assign only characters then that would be sufficient. In ASCII, the numbers, lowercase characters, and uppercase characters are a contiguous set. I was curious to see how this assignment may be done independent of how the characters are encoded on various systems (Non-ASCII).

Comment: In what sense do you want to “randomize” the characters? Why would selecting a random `char` value not be useful to you? Does it matter if it is printable or not? Does it have to pass through a mail system unaltered? What are the exact requirements? Are the input characters all printable? What about newline characters and other special characters?

Answer (score 0):

**C code character encoding is independent of data is may use.**

The character set of C code is *independent* of the encoding of the potential strings it may use.  One can readily write C code in ASCII that manipulates strings that are EBCDIC or UTF-8.

One could assert a `uint32_t` would suffice for any given character, but once one enters into the UTF world, though the maximum *code point* is '\U0010FFFF', multiple code points may make up a character.  Any UTF has lots of alphanumeric characters, too.

Suppose code is limited the randomise 36 alphanumeric characters: 0-9,A-Z. Using a table look-up as suggested would work in the limited case for various encodings like ASCII, EBCDIC, UTF-8, UTF16-BE, UTF16-BE, UTF32-BE, UTF32-BE.  Each table entry would need to use explicit values and in an endian independent fashion.  Consider little endian as follows.

```
typedef enum eEncoding {
  eASCII,
  eUTF16BE,
  eUTF16LE,
  ...
  eEncoding_N
};
unit8_t Table[eEncoding_N][36][5];
Table[eASCII][10 /* A */] = { 48, 0, 0, 0, 1 /* Length */ }
Table[eASCII][11 /* B */] = { 49, 0, 0, 0, 1 /* Length */ }
Table[eEBCIDIC][10]       = {193, 0, 0, 0, 1 /* Length */ }
Table[eUTF16BE][10]       = {  0,48, 0, 0, 2 /* Length */ }
Table[eUTF16LE][10]       = { 48, 0, 0, 0, 2 /* Length */ }
...
```